# Beamer alert in Math mode

Tags: beamer, overlays, dcolumn

I'm trying to alert my audience to numbers in a table that uses the `dcolumn` alignment environment. `\alert` works when it's used in a normal table cell, as below.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Table}
\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{3}D{.}{.}{3}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Both}   \\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
{\itshape Variables } & \beta & t\text{-stat} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{{\bfseries 2 Vehicles}}\\ 
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Current Alternative Share$)$ &  -0.417^{***} & -22.1  \\
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Past Alternative Share$)$ &   &  \\
\midrule
$\rho^2_C$  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\alert<2>{0.0903}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: First]
[image: alerted]

It does not work, however, when used in the `dcolumn` cells. The frame below fails with a `missing \endgroup inserted` error.

```
\begin{frame}{Table}
\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{3}D{.}{.}{3}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Both}   \\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
{\itshape Variables }& 
 \beta & t\text{-stat} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{{\bfseries 2 Vehicles}}\\ 
%% ALERT CELL %%
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Current Alternative Share$)$ & \alert<3>{-0.417^{***}} & -22.1  \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Past Alternative Share$)$ &  &  \\
\midrule
$\rho^2_C$  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\alert<2>{0.0903}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

I can alert the text with `\text{\alert<n>{x}}` but then I lose the alignment and math formatting. `\text{\alert<n>{$x$}}` doesn't work.

[image: Not working alert]

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new column type similar to `D` that includes the alert specification:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{A}[4]{>{\begin{alertenv}<#4>\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end\end{alertenv}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table}
\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{3}D{.}{.}{3}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Both}   \\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
{\itshape Variables }& 
 \beta & t\text{-stat} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{{\bfseries 2 Vehicles}}\\ 
%% ALERT CELL %%
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Current Alternative Share$)$ & \multicolumn{1}{A{.}{.}{3}{3}}{-0.417^{***}} & -22.1  \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Past Alternative Share$)$ &  &  \\
\midrule
$\rho^2_C$  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\alert<2>{0.0903}}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

These types of constructs are mentioned at the end of the `dcolumn` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could fake the alignment using some overlapping:

[image]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Table}
\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{3}D{.}{.}{3}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Both}   \\
 \cmidrule{2-3}
{\itshape Variables } & \beta & t\text{-stat} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{{\bfseries 2 Vehicles}}\\ 
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Current Alternative Share$)$ &  \text{\alert<2>{$-0$\rlap{.417$^{***}$}}} & -22.1  \\
\hspace*{1em} $\log($Past Alternative Share$)$ &   &  \\
\midrule
$\rho^2_C$  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\alert<2>{0.0903}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`\text` turns of the math-mode formatting, so it's re-activated by using `$...$`. The same goes for `\rlap`, which provides a `r`ight over`lap` (zero-width box that is left-aligned) of content.